# why TemplateDoesNotExist at / index.html

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

The error message is:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
index.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
index.html
Exception Location: C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  C:\Python310\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\31-5-22 Django\\wscubetech_firstproject',
 'C:\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Python310',
 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 04 Jun 2022 17:38:04 +0000
```

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def aboutUs(request):

    return HttpResponse('hello BD')

def homePage(request):

    return render(request,"index.html")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from wscubetech_firstproject import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('about-us/',views.aboutUs),
    path('',views.homePage),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR,"templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Project structure:
[image]

Comment: could you please post your project file structure ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the TEMPLATES setting a bit.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/"templates"], # right here
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

BASE_DIR object is pathlib.Path instance and the slash operator helps create child paths, similarly to os.path.join().

For more information you can check out the [pathlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).